# Sitting on a wet chair on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Would one be allowed to sit on a soaking wet metal or wood or plastic chair on Shabbos, or would this be forbidden because he would thus be "laundering" his pants or because he might come to squeeze out his pants?

Comment: I thought you were going to ask if this would negate תשבו כעין תדורו

Comment: How is getting rained on laundering? Why not ask if someone is allowed to be in the rain at all in shabbos?

Comment: @Laser123 i didn't ask about being rained on.  i'm asking where the rain has already stopped, but the chair is soaking wet.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I recommend that you generalize this question. This  is not really a succa question, but rather a Shabbat / melacha question. In other words, you're jsut asking of one may sit on a wet surface on Shabbat.